# Microk8s bare-metal kubernetes server loadbalancer and ingress routing issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service, microk8s, bare-metal-server

I have the installed latest microk8s and enabled `nginx-ingress` and `metallb` addons

I have everything configured and works well, but I can't seem to get to connect traffic between:

`x-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller` service

```
NAME                                TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                      AGE
x-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller   LoadBalancer   10.152.183.90    192.168.89.165   80:31080/TCP,443:31443/TCP
```

and the ingress itself

```
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS                 ADDRESS     PORTS     AGE
x-ingress         <none>   x.com + 83 more...   127.0.0.1   80, 443   2d8h
```

Also, the ingress appears to bind to address `127.0.0.1`. From reading through the project, i understand that this is correct, although I previously (kubeadm, cloud providers) used to get a load balancer ip (ex `192.168.89.165` instead of `127.0.0.1` in this case)

Please note that the node is on a different ip `192.168.89.160` than the loadbalancer, as per MetalLb documentation

The ingress is working and serving traffic correctly when `curl`-ed on `127.0.0.1`

`curl`-ing `192.168.89.165`, or `10.152.183.90`(the loadbalancer cluster ip) is failing with `'connection refused'`

Is this correct behaviour, is there a problem with the setup, how to connect route traffic from the loadbalanced ingress service?  I must be missing something, but can't figure out what

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you accessing it by providing its host name ? I mean something like `curl --header 'Host: hello-world.info' http://10.0.2.15`

Comment: @mario  Accessing it by the Service ClusterIp and Pod ClusterIp works. by Ingress ip also works, and by ingress using the domain name also works. By the loadbalancer Ip and (obviously) the external router Ip doesn't, since I can't get the routing between the loadbalancer and ingress to work. Any ideas on what to try next?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution ? Ingress bound only to `127.0.0.1` seems a bit strange. Can you share its yaml manifest ?